# Are there any trend line Function in PL SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need a function to calculate a trend line. I have a query (part of the function):

```
select round(sum(nvl(vl_indice, vl_meta))/12, 2) from (
SELECT 
  SUM (vl_indice) vl_indice, SUM (vl_meta) vl_meta
FROM
  (SELECT cd_mes, vl_indice, NULL vl_meta, dt.id_tempo,
    fi.id_multi_empresa, fi.id_setor, fi.id_indice
  FROM dbadw.fa_indice fi , dbadw.di_tempo dt ,
    dbadw.di_multi_empresa dme , dbaportal.organizacao o ,
    dbadw.di_indice di
  WHERE fi.id_tempo        = dt.id_tempo
  AND DT.CD_MES BETWEEN TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(PCD_MES),'YYYYMM'),- 11),'YYYYMM'))
                          AND PCD_MES
       AND DT.ANO = TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(PCD_MES),'YYYYMM'),'YYYY'))
  AND fi.id_multi_empresa  = dme.id_multi_empresa
  AND dme.cd_multi_empresa = NVL(o.cd_multi_empresa_mv2000, o.cd_organizacao)
  AND o.cd_organizacao     = PCD_ORG
  AND fi.id_setor         IS NULL
  AND fi.id_indice         = di.id_indice
  AND di.cd_indice         = PCD_IVM
  UNION ALL
  SELECT cd_mes, NULL vl_indice, vl_meta, dt.id_tempo,
    fm.id_multi_empresa, fm.id_setor, fm.id_indice
  FROM dbadw.fa_meta_indice fm , dbadw.di_tempo dt ,
    dbadw.di_multi_empresa dme , dbaportal.organizacao o ,
    dbadw.di_indice di
  WHERE fm.id_tempo        = dt.id_tempo
  AND DT.ANO = TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(PCD_MES),'YYYYMM'),'YYYY'))
  AND fm.id_multi_empresa  = dme.id_multi_empresa
  AND dme.cd_multi_empresa = NVL(o.cd_multi_empresa_mv2000, o.cd_organizacao)
  AND o.cd_organizacao     = PCD_ORG
  AND fm.id_setor         IS NULL
  AND fm.id_indice         = di.id_indice
  AND di.cd_indice         = PCD_IVM
  )
GROUP BY cd_mes, id_tempo, id_multi_empresa, id_setor, id_indice
ORDER BY cd_mes);
```

Where I tried to calculate the trend line on the first line, but is not correct. Please, Can anybody help me?

Comment: What type of trend line?  Linear regression, logarithmic regression, polynomial, something else?

Comment: Thank you @MatBailie . Is the linear

Comment: Edit your question with some sample data (i.e. the output of your query) and your expected result and you may get a better answer. As it stands, your code is very confusing as to what it is producing (it appears to be a single value) and there is no indication of which columns would correspond to x or y values to fit a trend-line to so its not possible to give an answer as we can't understand what you are doing.

Answer (score 3):

Its very difficult to work out from a query what you want to fit a "trend line" to - by which I assume you mean to use least square linear regression to find a best fit to the data.

So an example with test data:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE data ( x, y ) AS
SELECT LEVEL,
       230 + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(-5,5) - 3.14159 * DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE( 0.95, 1.05 ) * LEVEL
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1000;
```

As you can see the data is random but its approximately `y = -3.14159x + 230`

**Query - Get the Least Square Regression y-intercept and gradient**:

```
SELECT REGR_INTERCEPT( y, x ) AS best_fit_y_intercept,
       REGR_SLOPE( y, x ) AS best_fit_gradient
FROM   data
```

This will get something like:

```
best_fit_y_intercept best_fit_gradient
-------------------- -----------------
230.531799878168     -3.143190435415
```

**Query - Get the y co-ordinate of the line of best fit**:

```
SELECT x,
       y,
       REGR_INTERCEPT( y, x ) OVER () + x * REGR_SLOPE( y, x ) OVER () AS best_fit_y
FROM   data
```

Comment: thank you...I dont make it. The result of my query is as follows:
CD_MES    VL_INDICE(value)    ID_MULTI_EMPRESA  ------------------
200902          1068                            1                           -------------------
200903          1288                            1                           ------------------- 
.............................................................................................................. 
200912          1119                             1

Please, How can I use the formula with this data? It's possible?

Comment: I got it..

solution: 

SELECT valor, mes, ((mes * SLOPE) + INTERCEPT) TENDENCIA, SLOPE, INTERCEPT 
from(
select valor, mes, ROUND(REGR_SLOPE(valor,mes) over 
(partition by id_multi_empresa),4)SLOPE,
ROUND(REGR_INTERCEPT(valor,mes) over 
(PARTITION by id_multi_empresa),4) INTERCEPT from(   
....
Thank you guys for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
SELECT valor, mes, 
((mes * SLOPE) + INTERCEPT) TENDENCIA, SLOPE, INTERCEPT from
( select valor, mes, ROUND(REGR_SLOPE(valor,mes) over (partition by id_multi_empresa),4)SLOPE, 
ROUND(REGR_INTERCEPT(valor,mes) over (PARTITION by id_multi_empresa),4) INTERCEPT from( --the initial select
```